# Which mushroom could be this?

Tags: mushroom

[image]

Collected in northern West Europe in autumn 2017[image]

Comment: It's a [shelf mushroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polypore) (pores or tubes on the underside) or polyspore (are also called bracket fungi.) How specific an answer do you want? Some are edible (e.g. 'chicken of the woods'), some are lethal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a hint from a FB forum, it should be *meripilus giganteus* and I have to agree.